# How to create a generic Interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I want to create a generic interface which must have 2 methods. The interface should accept `TInput` and returns `TOutput`. When implemented in a class and provide the type for `TInput` and `TOutput`, the class implementation should be as below.

```
public class EmployeeFactory : IBaseFactory<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>  
{    
    Employee Convert(EmployeeViewModel employees);   
    IQueryable<Employee> Convert (IQueryable<EmployeeViewModel> employees);

}
```

I tried creating the interface but this seems not completely correct. Can someone help me!!

```
public interface IBaseFactory<in TInput, out TOutput>   
{       
     TOutput Convert(TInput input);            
}
```

Comment: "but this seems not completely correct". Why? Do you get an error message? Or is it not working as expected?

Comment: You don't need `in` and `out` unless you intend to use classes *derived* from `EmployeeViewModel` and `Employee` at runtime.

Comment: The assignment says "create a generic interface which must have 2 methods", and an example implemenation. You create an interface which has 1 method. What keeps you from defining the second method?

Comment: Add `public` modifier to method implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your interface has one method but in class you have two methods, if you want to implement also second method from interface, your missing inside of interface.

```
IQueryable<TOutput> Convert(IQueryable<TInput> inputs);
```